# Unable to place array as a Json object Value in my angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have array of JSON objects.

Now I want to pass these arrays as a values to another JSON object in my angular js code as below

```
` $scope.actions= [ 
            {
              "item": "item value1",
              "remark": "remark1"    } , 
   {
              "item": "item value2",
              "remark": "remark2"            } 
]

$scope.arr2= [ 
            {
              "key1": "value1",
              "key2" "value2"
            } , 
            {
              "key1": "value1",
              "key2" "value2"
            }]

var jsonObj={

              "firstArr":$scope.actions,

              "secondArr":$scope.arr2;

}      `

    

    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    $scope.actions= [ 
                {
                  "item": "item value1",
                  "remark": "remark1"    } , 
       {
                  "item": "item value2",
                  "remark": "remark2"            } 
    ]

    $scope.arr2= [ 
                {
                  "key1": "value1",
                  "key2" "value2"
                } , 
                {
                  "key1": "value1",
                  "key2" "value2"
                }]

    var jsonObj={

                  "firstArr":$scope.actions,
        
                  "secondArr":$scope.arr2;

    }
```

But if I print jsonObj on console 
I am getting empty arrays instead of their original values as below

```
{
"firstArr":[],
"secondArr":[];
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

the `arr2` json object is invalid. need `:` in between `key2` and `value2`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

 

$scope.actions = [{
        "item": "item value1",
        "remark": "remark1"
    },
    {
        "item": "item value2",
        "remark": "remark2"
    }
]

$scope.arr2 = [{
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
]

var jsonObj = {
    "firstArr": $scope.actions,
    "secondArr": $scope.arr2
}   

console.log(jsonObj)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sachila for your quick response.
Here I forgot to post,
but in my actual code ':' is there as you said
like "key2":"value2"

but still I am getting empty array as a result

Answer (score 0):

The the below code .

You missed : in array structure. Object literals are not end with semi colons

```
$scope.actions= [{
              "item": "item value1",
              "remark": "remark1"} , 
              {
              "item": "item value2",
              "remark": "remark2"  } 
];

$scope.arr2= [{
              "key1": "value1",
              "key2": "value2"}, 
            {
              "key1": "value1",
              "key2": "value2" }
              ];

var jsonObj={

              "firstArr":$scope.actions,      
              "secondArr":$scope.arr2
};
```